# Where is the source code that allows new coins to be generated?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, mining-reward, coinbase-transaction, reward-schedule

As per Bitcoin documentation, new coins are generated and brought into circulation when miner receive the reward. 
I am not talking about existing coins that are collected at the time of mining.

Can somebody guide me, where exactly this generation of new coins takes place?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the method [`CAmount GetBlockSubsidy(int nHeight, const Consensus::Params& consensusParams)` in `validation.cpp`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v22.0/src/validation.cpp#L1186-L1197).

```
CAmount GetBlockSubsidy(int nHeight, const Consensus::Params& consensusParams)
{
    int halvings = nHeight / consensusParams.nSubsidyHalvingInterval;
    // Force block reward to zero when right shift is undefined.
    if (halvings >= 64)
        return 0;

    CAmount nSubsidy = 50 * COIN;
    // Subsidy is cut in half every 210,000 blocks which will occur approximately every 4 years.
    nSubsidy >>= halvings;
    return nSubsidy;
}
```

The variables in this code snippet stand for:

- `nHeight` is the number of blocks that have been found.
- `consensusParams.nSubsidyHalvingInterval` is 210000 blocks, the duration of reward epochs and the interval between the halvings
- `COIN` is 10<sup>8</sup>, the number of satoshis in one bitcoin
- `nSubsidy` finally gives the number of satoshis that may be generated per block